# Google Fusion Table - creating new table using Google API client for PHP

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

The following code results in 400 Bad Request... can you see any obvious problems?

```
$column = new Google_Column();
$column->setName('foo');
$column->setType('TEXT');

$table = new Google_Table();
$table->setName('bar');
$table->setColumns(array($column));

// $client below is a successfully authenticated Google_Client instance 
$service = new Google_FusiontablesService($client); 
$result = $service->table->insert($table);  // 400 Bad Request exception thrown
```

Google_Client is authenticated with a "service account" and I'm able to run other requests, e.g. `$service->query->sql()` successfully.

Google API client version is 0.6.2 (up-to-date).

Thanks.

**Update:** request object dump:

```
Google_HttpRequest Object
(
    [batchHeaders:Google_HttpRequest:private] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/http
            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => binary
            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
            [Content-Length] =>
        )

    [url:protected] => https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables
    [requestMethod:protected] => POST
    [requestHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
            [content-length] => 162
            [authorization] => Bearer someHashHere
        )

    [postBody:protected] => {"columns":[{"name":"Project","type":"TEXT"}],"description":"Created on 2013-05-14 10:41:44","isExportable":"true","name":"foobar"}
    [userAgent:protected] => My app name google-api-php-client/0.6.0
    [responseHttpCode:protected] =>
    [responseHeaders:protected] =>
    [responseBody:protected] =>
    [accessKey] =>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so simple after you see it, "TEXT" is not a valid column type. You need to use "STRING" instead.

Answer (score 0):

The isExportable bit is also a required parameter when creating a table (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/insert) .  What happens when you set that?

Comment: No, it might be required, but it doesn't have any effect on that error :( I've got an example from the Fusion Tables newsgroup: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/detail?id=192#c4 will look into it later and update if it helps.

Comment: That link I posted earlier turned out to be irrelevant, updated my post with request dump.